# Parcel watch doesn't detect changes, but safe-write is off

Tags: intellij-idea, asset-pipeline, inotify, parceljs

**Symptoms:**

- Starting parcel watch completes the initial build, the command continues running but doesn't detect any further changes

**Context:**

- Parcel is being run from an IntelliJ IDEA platform IDE (Rider)
- Safe-write functionality is **disabled**, so I am completely sure that the file is actually being changed on disk

  - Problem is reproducible when I edit referenced CSS or JS using a different editor (vim)
- OS is Ubuntu Linux

Why aren't subsequent changes to files detected by Parcel, triggering a re-build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ-based IDEs have a habit of completely burning through the inotify limit. In my case, setting `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to a higher value (524288 in my case, in accordance with the instructions [given by JetBrains](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit)) and then running `sudo sysctl -p --system` before restarting `parcel watch` solved the problem conclusively.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can set up a file watcher inside intellij that runs `touch` on the file. Just make sure it doesn't trigger on external file changes, or you'll loop forever. This way, you can leave safe write on and still trigger parcel and other external watchers.